# How to generate url slug from chinese characters?

Tags: javascript

Normally for generating url slug I use https://github.com/jprichardson/string.js library - and exactly `slugify` method. However it removes all chinese characters. As a workaround I use following function:

```
var slugify = function(str){
   str = str.replace(/\s+/g,'-') // replace spaces with dashes
   str = encodeURIComponent(str) // encode (it encodes chinese characters)
   return str
}
```

So for input `中文 标题` I get `%E4%B8%AD%E6%96%87-%E6%A0%87%E9%A2%98` and it looks like this in web browser url input box (and it works):

```
http://example.com/中文-标题
```

However I want to also remove any special characters like `!@#$%^&*)` etc. The problem is that `string.js` library is using following piece of code internally:

```
.replace(/[^\w\s-]/g
```

And it removes any special characters, BUT ALSO removes chinese characters as they don't match with `\w` regexp...

So my question is - how to modify above regexp so make it keep chinese characters?

---

I tried

```
replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9_\s-\u3400-\u9FBF]/g,'')
```

But it still replaces chinese characters...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to match (or exclude) the dash `-` character in a set of characters (with square brackets), you have to put it in the end.

Your regexp matches characters that are not

- in the range `a-z`
- in the range `A-Z`
- in the range `0-9`
- `_`
- in the range `\s-\u3400`     *that's your problem*
- `-`
- `\u9FBF`

You want to do:

```
replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9_\u3400-\u9FBF\s-]/g,'')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try [uslug](https://github.com/jeremys/uslug), which slugify `汉语/漢語` to `汉语漢語`

If you want to transform Chinese characters to Pinyin, try [transliteration](https://github.com/dzcpy/transliteration)

Answer (score 0):

do a positive match list:

```
  replace(/[\!@#\$%^&\*\)]/g,'')
```

Anyway I would consider to take URL meta chars out of that:

```
   replace(/[\!@\$\^\*\)]/g,'')
```